# Is there a way to inherit from the javascript Node interface?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to write some javascript classes which inherit from the DOM Node interface... Sounds very much like [how-to-inherit-from-the-dom-element-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489738/how-to-inherit-from-the-dom-element-class), but I do not want to use its instances it in my [X|XHT|HT]ML document. My aim is to build a absolutely **stand-alone DOM tree**, so I would like to use the [Node interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node) provided by modern browsers instead of creating my own DOM implementation. The nodes should not have any HTML attributes like classname, styles or (client)offsets - just a plain *Node*. The class doesn't need to be extensible, the Node methods would be enough.

I would also be happy if there was a possibility to create a DocumentFragment or a new Document which
a) is not a (X)HTML document but a XML document and
b) is not associated with the current document (as in [document.implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.implementation))

The script should work in the latest versions of Opera and Firefox. Other browsers are a nice-to-have, not a must; and I don't care about any old versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that this is the closest to my requirements:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString("<root />", "text/xml");
```

But still no way to inherit from the Node interface.

Answer (score 0):

No. [`Node`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-node) is an abstract interface. It does not have [a `constructor` operation](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-constructors), which means that you can neither construct it nor inherit from it. It [just throws](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-object):

> [Interface objects](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-interface-object) whose [interfaces](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-interface) are not declared with a [constructor operation](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-constructors) will throw when called, both as a function and as a [constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#constructor).

So while you can write `class Sub extends Node {}`, you could never instantiate it. Similarly, inheriting from `Node.prototype` is possible but pointless since all the builtin methods require the internal fields.