# Creating instances of predefined objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, window, document

I know that in Javascript we can create ,instatnces of object like

```
var ins = new myObject();
```

I know that ,window ,document etc are predefined objects in javascript..Can we create new instances of these objects.?
For  ex:
Is

```
var inss = new document();
```

possible?

Comment: You can simulate your own constructor functions for DOM Elements. Take [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom "jsdom") for example.

Comment: I dont think so. Trying this var inss = new document(); on console give error "TypeError: object is not a function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse *objects* with *constructors* (or *classes* in most OOP languages).  In JavaScript, you create objects by calling constructor functions using the `new` operator:

```
function MyObject()
{
}

var obj = new MyObject();
```

Afterwards you can access the constructor given the object using the `constructor` property:

```
var ctor = obj.constructor;  // (ctor === MyObject) will be true
```

Theoretically, you can create new objects of the same type as a given object:

```
var obj1 = new MyObject();
var obj2 = new obj1.constructor();
```

In your case, you might try the same with "built-in" object, but it will probably not work since the script engine might forbid it.  For example, Chrome will throw `TypeError: Illegal constructor` when trying to create a new document using `new document.constructor()`.  This is because `document`'s constructor, `HTMLDocument`, is not meant to be used directly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no, mostly no.

You can create a new `window` object using `window.open`. It will also have a new `document` object.

You can create a new DOM `document` via [`createDocument`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Level-2-Core-DOM-createDocument), though it won't necessarily have all the special features of the pre-made one. You can also create a new document *fragment* via [`createDocumentFragment`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-35CB04B5), which can be very handy.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Although most of these host objects have constructors (e.g. `HTMLDocument` for `document`), they are only used for inheritance feautures (e.g. the `instanceof` operator) but can not be invoked.

```
> document.constructor
HTMLDocument
> new HTMLDocument
Unhandled DOMException: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR
```

You also can't create [`Node`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8217457/1048572) for example, these "constructors" are just interfaces.

Yet, you can create a new DOM with the [`createDocument`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Level-2-Core-DOM-createDocument) method, which is available at the [`document.implementation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.implementation) object.

Answer (score 1):

[The new operator only works with objects that are user defined, or built-ins that have a constructor.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) document and window don't have constructors.

Comment: documents have constructors, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`document` is not a constructor, it's a constructed object. What you are trying to do is like saying `new new Object()` or `new {}`.

The constructor of `document` is `HTMLDocument` but you cannot construct it that way, you must use `document.implementation.createDocument()`