# Angular2 + Jasmine Event Object

Tags: angular, jasmine, dom-events, istanbul, angular2-testing

I have this simple method which needs to be tested:

```
  public onLayerContainerClick(event: Event): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.srcElement.classList.contains('dpm-info__layerContainer')) {
     this.closeInfoLayer(event);
    }
  }
```

My objective is actually to increase code coverage for the component. If I test is like this:

```
  it( 'should close on info container click', () => {
    spyOn( component, 'onLayerContainerClick' );
    const el: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query( By.css( '.dpm-info__layerContainer' ) );
    el.triggerEventHandler( 'click', null );
    expect( component.onLayerContainerClick ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  } );
```

the test is OK, but instanbul says "function not covered". So I guess, I need to call the function explicitly? To do that, I need to have a full event object, including (at least) srcTarget property. How do I define such an event within the unit test?

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the function with a mocked event in the test. 
`component.onLayerContainerClick({ srcElement: { value: 'mock_value' } });`

And then write what you expect

`expect( component.closeInfoLayer ).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Maybe this https://angular.io/guide/testing#triggereventhandler might help as well

Comment: The challenge is the Typescript, which expects the argument passed in to `onLayerContainerClick` to be of type `Event`. Just passing an object with `srcTarget` property doesn't cut it - I get a type error.

Comment: ok, can you post also the `beforeEach ` at the beginning of each test ? 

btw, if you try component.onLayerContainerClick(<any>{ srcElement: { value: 'mock_value' } }); or <Event> do u get errors ?

Comment: @pop Not a challenge. The types are there to help you, not to create obstacles. You can pass any argument you need with `<any>arg` or `<Event><any>arg`.

Comment: yes, for mocking input data it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Well, I am over the first hurdle, and am able to construct an object of type Event, just as you guys say. However (here we go), this line in the component `event.srcElement.classList.contains` expects `classList` to be of type `DOMTokenList` which has its own methods and properties (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172515/constructing-a-domtokenlist-domsettabletokenlist-instance).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to estus and DrNio I've come up with this test, which makes istanbul code coverage happy and doesn't have any type problems:

```
  it( 'should close on info container click', () => {
    spyOn( component, 'closeInfoLayer' );
    const el: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.dpm-info__layerContainer')).nativeElement;
    const mockEvent: Event = <Event><any>{
      srcElement: {
        classList: el.classList
      },
      stopPropagation: <any>( ( e: any ) => { /**/ }),
      preventDefault: <any>( ( e: any ) => { /**/ }),
    };

    component.onLayerContainerClick( mockEvent );
    expect( component.closeInfoLayer ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  } );
```

Comment: i think you don't need the `spyOn( component, 'closeInfoLayer' );`. I think this is used mostly when you want to check function calls of external services, ex: `spyOn(myService, 'aMethodThere');`

Comment: well, I need *something* to test again. no variable is set in that method and the only outcome is the function call. so this is what I test - it being called. how else?

Comment: if u delete `spyOn( component, 'closeInfoLayer' );` it should work, cause it will pass the if statement since u mock the event. give it a try and let us know

Comment: what should I `expect` then? just deleting `spyOn` and leaving `expect` will throw error.

Comment: can you post the error here ? i think if it throws error it means that it didn't pass the if statement and the `closeInfoLayer ` was not called