# Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined; CoffeeScript inheritance with Require.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs

I'm using Require.js and CoffeeScript. I have what I find to be a rather strange error.

I have the following definition:

```
define ->
    {
        Node: class

        ChildNode: class extends @Node

        Term: class

        ChildTerm: class extends @Term

    }
```

This raises the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

However, the following both work fine:

```
define ->
    {
        Node: class

        ChildNode: class extends @Node

    }



define ->
    {
        Node: class

        ChildNode: class extends @Node

        Term: class

        ChildTerm: class extends @Node

    }
```

What is wrong with my code such that I can't extend `Term`? I can't see anything different between it and `Node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the following both work fine

Actually they don't. Have a look at what code they're producing:

```
// [simplified, obviously]
function __extends(child, parent) {
  child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
  return child; //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
define(function() {
  return {
    Node: function _Class() {},
    ChildNode: __extends(function _Class() {}, this.Node)
  } //                                         ^^^^^^^^^
})
```

You cannot have [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572).

> So why does subclassing `Term` like this throw an error while with `Node` it does not?

Because the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) does refer to the global object. And that does actually have a `Node` property already: the [DOM `Node` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) constructor (which you [cannot subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8217457/1048572), though). With `Term` however, you are passing `undefined` to `__extend()`.