# How to create a class which inherits from Document

Tags: javascript, dom, inheritance

I want to create a class called `NMLDocument` which inherits from `Document` but has some additional properties.

I've tried this code:

```
NMLDocument.prototype = Object.create(Document.prototype);
```

But the browser throws the following error:

```
Ignoring get or set of property that has [LenientThis] because the "this" object is incorrect.
```

Is there any way around? (I don't want to include all the properties separately)

Comment: I don't think this is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217457/is-there-a-way-to-inherit-from-the-javascript-node-interface). You might better use a wrapper.

Comment: Browsers aren't required to make in-built functions (like console.log or document.createElement) play nicely. In some cases you simply can't use the function like a typical JavaScript function (assigning them new aliases, etc.). So you'll struggle at best. Anyway this sounds like an X-Y problem; what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, please expand on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm writing my own test-browser based on XULRunner to test my ideas about how could HTML and XML evolve. I've already got a custom parse but the I need another type of Document for it.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to achieve probably isn't possible since internal types like `Document` don't have to behave like normal JS objects (usually, `Document` won't because of security reasons).

If you want to simulate a browser, you can try [envjs](http://www.envjs.com/) which is a pretty complete implementation of a browser in pure JavaScript.

If you need a real browser, try [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). That's a WebKit-based browser which is controlled by JavaScript or CoffeeScript. It offers many nice APIs on the controlling side (like listeners for resource loading).

If you want to use XULRunner, try to write a wrapper or overwrite specific parts of `Document`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check out phantom.js