# Extending DOM but NOT element prototype.. possible?

Tags: javascript, dom, element, extend

I would like to extend some group or class if you want in DOM but I dont want to have all lements extended. It is possible?

for example:

```
document.getElementsByClass('extended').myMethod(); // working
```

BUT

```
document.getElementById('elementNotExtendedClass').myMethod(); // shouldnt be working
```

Because I dont want to mess all elements, just the selected ones.
Maybe it should be done somehow by creating my own version of createElement() method in document. For example document.CreateMyElement().

Or any ideas? Thanks

Edit June 06:
I am looking for solution where prototype chain retains working, so I can change some shared methods and properties at once.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? Why do you need this?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: My goal is to make simple wysiwyg features for webpage. I mean that editor of the page just start editable mode and lot of stuff is editable. So I think that extend some elements with my methods and properties could be the best way how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add the method to each instance ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7sPt/4))

```
function test() {
    this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}

window.onload = function(){
    // add your method to existing elements with class 'extended'
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('extended');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){        
        elements[i].test = test;
    }
    // just to visualize what happened...
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    alert("span[0].test: " + typeof spans[0].test
          +"\nspan[1].test: " + typeof spans[1].test); 
    spans[0].test();
};
```

Comment: This works, but I dont want to loose prototype chain, so if I would need to change test function, I have to distribute this function for all elements with "extended" class. I was looking for solution where prototype chain is working, so I can change some shared methods and properties at once. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This approach would define a global interface onto which you define the extension methods. Having them inside an interface like this allows you to change the method without having to reapply it.

```
MyExtendedInterface = {
    test: function() {
        // this points to the DOM element itself
        console.log(this);
    }
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('extended');
for (var i = 0, el; el = elements[i]; ++i) {
    for (var j in MyExtendedInterface) {
        // bind the interface methods to the current element
        el[j] = MyExtendedInterface[j].bind(el);
    }
}
```

---

The `.bind()` is a recent addition to JavaScript; see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Luckylooke I've updated the answer, hope this is something you'd like more :)

Comment: I have to do some testing with your snippet first. In the meantime I have found interesting partial answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489738/how-to-inherit-from-the-dom-element-class) And most interesting answer is from kangax and he was writing about wrapper or decorator patterns at the end. But I am curious how this patterns should be used in the case.