# How to copy objects inside constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, object, constructor, src

**I want to create a custom image constructor:**

```
var image1 = new imgConstructor("picture.png", 100, 50);
```

I have tried:

```
var imgConstructor = function(src, width, height) {
    this = new Image(width, height);
    this.src = src;
}
```

but `this = new Image()`is invalid.

I know I can do it with factory function like:

```
var imgConstructor = function(src, width, height) {
    var img = new Image(width, height);
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}
var image1 = imgConstructor("picture.png", 100, 50);
```

But I want to do with constructor, using *"new"*. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I want to do with constructor, using `new`. Any ideas?

No, that's not possible. You won't be able to subclass `Image`after all. If you needed "instances" with your own methods, better create a wrapper object (like doing `this.img = new Image(…)` in your constructor).

Using a factory function is totally fine, it just seems to be appropriate here. If you want to use `new` for some reason, you can use `new` on your factory function and it will still work (though yielding the `Image`, not an instance of `imgConstructor`).

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me what is the disadvantage of "yielding the Image, not an instance of imgConstructor"?

Comment: When someone calls `new imgConstructor`, one would usually expect that the result is an instance of `imgConstructor`. It is not always, as when the constructor `return`s an object explicitly that might be something different.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance won't help you here. Because [Image](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-img-element) can't be inherited. [See why here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489738/how-to-inherit-from-the-dom-element-class)

Basic explanation:

```
var a = new Image();
console.log(a.constructor); // Should be function Image() { [native code] }
// OUTPUT: function HTMLImageElement() { [native code] }

var b = new HTMLImageElement();
// Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

So, your solution is corret.

**EDIT:**
The solution from @user86745458 is working but as @Bergi said:

> When someone calls new imgConstructor, one would usually expect that
>   the result is an instance of imgConstructor. It is not always, as when
>   the constructor returns an object explicitly that might be something
>   different.

Try applying the old solution (from @user86745458) and check:

```
new imgConstructor() instanceof imgConstructor
// OUTPUT: false 
imgConstructor() instanceof imgConstructor
// OUTPUT: false
imgConstructor() instanceof Image
// OUTPUT: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something like this

```
var imgConstructor = function(src, width, height) {
    var img = this;
    img = new Image(width, height);
    img.onload = function(){
      // image  has been loaded
    };
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesnt return the image I think. I want to return the image object and load it afterwards

Comment: Why it is not working: `var img = this;` Ok, storing the reference to `this` object.

`img = new Image(width, height);` Throwing away the last reference and storing a new reference.

Comment: You added the "return img;" line? Now it's working like a charm. I call it with image1 = new imgConstructor and it works fine. but the line "var img = this" is not needed? I removed it and the function still works